# Generate SQL migrations from exposed orm table

Tags: kotlin, flyway, kotlin-exposed

I'd like to know how can I generate SQL script migrations from my tables created using Exposed ORM. This would be very helpful for me since I can use Flyway to apply the migrations at a later point.

I'm using JDK 16 with Kotlin.

So the main question here would be: Is there any tool that can help me create these migration scripts?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SchemaUtils.createStatements()` to generate DDLs from your table definitions.

```
println(SchemaUtils.createStatements(Cities, Users).joinToString("\n\n") { "$it;" }
```

SchemaUtils.kt
https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/blob/621dc5b939b03c0f2396073c17f7ab5a7022816c/exposed-core/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/exposed/sql/SchemaUtils.kt#L93

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any documentation. But `SchemaUtils.create()` is using it internally. So it should work.

Exposed version: 0.36.2